# How to build Beanshell with maven?

Tags: maven, beanshell

I have a project `git clone --depth 1 --branch 2.0b6 https://github.com/beanshell/beanshell.git` which I consider a BeanShell version 2.0b6. And I want to build it as described in https://github.com/beanshell/beanshell/blob/master/README.md
"mvn install" - this produces 2838 bytes of JAR file which couldn't be a working library. Could you tell me how to build bsh-2.0b6.jar properly?

**UPD** I have changed <javac target to ="1.8" then ran "ant" and got the following error:

```
[javac] /home/katya/tmp_work/beanshell/src/bsh/util/AWTConsole.java:217: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         ((java.awt.peer.TextComponentPeer)getPeer()).setCaretPosition( 
[javac]                                           ^
[javac]   symbol:   method getPeer()
[javac]   location: class AWTConsole
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the [pom](https://github.com/beanshell/beanshell/blob/2.0b6/pom.xml) file which was used for 2.0b6 version doesn't look like it was supposed to allow users to actually build the project as the project structure wasn't following the default Maven file hierarchy. Normally this is how the src/ structure for a Maven project should look like:

```
src/
  main/
    java/
       com/
         mycompany/
           Main.java
```

However the [src/](https://github.com/beanshell/beanshell/tree/2.0b6/src) of 2.0b6 looks completely different (packages are right under the src/ directory without main/ and java/). This means that Maven cannot find classes to be included into a jar which in the end gives an 'empty' jar whenever `mvn install`   is called.

Answer (score 0):

You are following the wrong instructions.

The README that came with the version you downloaded is [here](https://github.com/beanshell/beanshell/blob/2.0b6/README.md). That does not have any instructions that explicitly tell you ho to build the project. However, considering the pom.xml in that version is almost empty, and considering there is a fully populated build.xml, I would conclude that version of the project needs to be built with [ant](https://ant.apache.org/).